# unchecking radio

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have some radio buttons in my html form
here is code:

```
slovenský <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="1" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
český     <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="2" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
anglický  <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="3" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
<br />
nemecký   <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="4" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
francúzsky<input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="5" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
španielsky<input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="6" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
<br />
taliansky <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="7" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
ruský     <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="8" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
maďarský  <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="9" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
<br />
poľský    <input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="10" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
```

And i want to add there link to reset this radio buttons, but only this radio buttons, cause i have there more radio buttons in one form...Can you help me please?

Comment: Jaktože tam nemáš Esperanto? :D

Answer (score 5):

Suppose a link like following:

```
<a href="#" id="uncheck">Uncheck</a>
```

and corresponding ***jQuery*** to `uncheck` `radio`s:

```
$('#uncheck').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload, you can remove it if you don't want
  $(':radio[name=jazyk1]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Here, `:radio[name=jazyk1]` only radio buttons with name exactly `jazyk1`. So if your other `radio`s don't have same name then above code will work for above `radio`s only.

Instead of link tag you can also use something other like `button` etc.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to ***thecodeparadox*** answer
you can also use `$(':radio[name=jazyk1]').attr('checked', false);` instead of `$(':radio[name=jazyk1]').prop('checked', false);` This will also work as same. `attr` is the most common jQuery method to play with element attributes.

Comment: What is your reference? Maybe you meant that `.attr` is most commonly misunderstood jQuery method

Comment: No @Esailija, I mean to say its most commonly used method.

Answer (score 0):

The (only) robust way of letting the user reset a set of radio buttons is to include an additional button that represents a “dummy” selection or, in practice, “no selection”, e.g.

```
<label for="no-select">Jazyk nie je vybraté</label>
<input type="radio" name="jazyk1" value="0" checked="checked" id="no-select"
       style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" />
```

The code that processes the form data (server-side or client-side) would then need to handle this selection accordingly: `jazyk1=0` would mean that no selection was made, either because the user did not click on any of those radio buttons or he has undone the selection. The special value, `0` in this case, needs to be one that does not occur as a genuine value.